# Use Media recorder to record audio and static image in android

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I record audio files with the following:

```
private void startRecording(){
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename(count_sound));
    recorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);


    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();


    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but is it possible while I record audio, to display as video one static image e.g app logo?

Comment: If u want a video container (mp4) u will need to mux audio  plus vid with something like ffmpeg

Comment: Where can I find how to use of this ffmpeg? is it official tool?